# TextMate: Comment-line shortcut does not work anymore (Cmd-/ or Cmd-Shift-7 on my swiss layout)

Tags: comments, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I experience a quite strange behavior in TextMate since some time.

I had troubles to use the keyboard shortcut for commenting a line (which is `Cmd-/` or on my swiss layout it is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> where <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> results in a `/`) a few times already since I switched to Lion 2 months ago (before I never had any problems). I then used to restart TextMate and it worked again.

But now, restart doesn't solve the problem. So I went into the Bundle Editor and tried to reset the shortcut, and there I can set it to anything I like, but not to `Cmd-/`! Nothing happens when I want to record the shortcut and press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>`, the input field stays blank!

I have some bundles installed since my switch to Lion (Cucumber, RSpec, RubyAMP, Ruby Debug, Shoulda), so maybe one of those makes troubles?? Or does the fact that I even don't seem to be able to send <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> in the Bundle Editor imply that the Shortcut is blocked from somewhere else "outside" of TextMate?

How should I debug this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) that was running and occupied `Cmd-Shift-7`.