# TextMate: Keyboard shortcuts sometimes don't work, then work again after restart

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I moved to Lion 2 months ago, and since then I sometimes encounter that a TextMate keyboard shortcut doesn't work anymore (which means: nothing happens), and then, after a restart of TextMate, it works again.

This time, it was <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, which should trigger Cucumber's `Go to current step` command. After restart of TM, it worked again. I also experienced this with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (which results in `Cmd-/` on my swiss layout) for commenting out lines.

Any idea about what's the problem? As I mentioned in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447283/textmate-comment-line-shortcut-does-not-work-anymore-cmd-or-cmd-shift-7-on-m), for the commenting out shortcut it finally happened to be the application Skitch sometimes which blocks this commend and prevents it from being sent to TM. But this doesn't have to do with the restart scenario I have now.

Anyway, it would be nice to have OSX display some info box whenever a keyboard shortcut is pressed which tells what exactly was executed, so e.g. when pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it would tell "Save Document", or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> "Take Screenshot", etc., so you'd always know what was triggered and don't have to think a shortcut ended up in Nirvana... Maybe there is some application or OSX extensions that does this?

Comment: I have the same issue with `CMD+S`

Comment: Sadly, I never figured this out. I'm using RubyMine now. Maybe I'll give TM2 a try sometime...

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when this happens, there's a background process going on that is, for some reason, disabling some or all of your keyboard shortcuts.  I also found that it's very easily remedied by typing Command-. (period) which tells TextMate to cancel the running background task.

Try it next time it happens and see if that doesn't at least ameliorate the problem.  Fixing it would require figuring out what background task is getting wedged and either fixing or eliminating it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't run into this problem for some time now but will keep your suggestion in mind.