# textmate remap 'comment line / selection' for php

Tags: binding, key, textmate

where can i find the 'comment line / selection' to remap the key binding?
i neither found anything in the 'text' bundle nor in 'php'.
i also tried to use mac's keyboard short cuts with 'comment line / selection' but as expected, it didn't work. 
best matching stackoverflow question i found was [TextMate: Comment-line shortcut does not work anymore (Cmd-/ or Cmd-Shift-7 on my swiss layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447283/textmate-comment-line-shortcut-does-not-work-anymore-cmd-or-cmd-shift-7-on-m)
but there is no answer for my setup.
thanks in advance,